# Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price::testPrice(Array(

Tags: magento, methods

I am trying to control the price text from Magento Admin panel and for that I have overwritten default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml and trying to change the line:

```
<span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Regular Price:') ?></span>
```

to

```
<span class="price-label"><?php $this->newPriceText(); ?></span>
```

I have created newPriceText(); method in local/MyCompany/Catalog/Block/Product/Price.php, which looks like this at the moment:

```
class MyCompany_Catalog_Block_Product_Price extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price
{
    public function newPriceText()
    {
        print_r('Testing Price Text');
    }
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:70:"Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price::testPrice(Array
(
)
)";i:1;s:4859:"#0 [internal function]: Varien_Object->__call('testPrice', Array)
#1 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\design\frontend\default\default\template\catalog\product\price.phtml(320): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price->testPrice()
#2 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(235): include('C:\wamp\www\mag...')
#3 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(266): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend\defaul...')
#4 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(280): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\Price.php(111): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(758): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price->_toHtml()
#7 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\Abstract.php(203): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#8 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml(100): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract->getPriceHtml(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), true)
#9 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(235): include('C:\wamp\www\mag...')
#10 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(266): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend\base\d...')
#11 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(280): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#12 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(758): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#13 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(525): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#14 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(476): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('product_list', true)
#15 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Category\View.php(85): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('product_list')
#16 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\category\view.phtml(70): Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View->getProductListHtml()
#17 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(235): include('C:\wamp\www\mag...')
#18 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(266): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend\base\d...')
#19 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(280): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#20 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(758): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#21 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Text\List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(758): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#23 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(525): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#24 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(476): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#25 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\3columns.phtml(49): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#26 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(235): include('C:\wamp\www\mag...')
#27 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(266): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend\base\d...')
#28 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(280): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#29 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(758): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#30 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(529): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#31 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(391): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#32 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\controllers\CategoryController.php(159): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#33 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(420): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#34 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(253): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#35 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#36 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(340): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#37 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\app\Mage.php(627): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#38 C:\wamp\www\mage_testing\index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#39 {main}";s:3:"url";s:27:"/mage_testing/products.html";s:11:"script_name";s:23:"/mage_testing/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}


}
```

I'm not sure where I'm doing it wrong. Any idea?

I'm still waiting for the answer. Please help?

"I am not sure how to write the layout xml for this."

Comment: The block being used is `Mage_Catalog_...` instead of `MyCompany_Catalog_...` How are you overriding that block with your own? Show the XML used.

Comment: I'm extending Mage_Catalog but my block is MyCompany_Catalog. Here is the xml:
`<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_Catalog>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </MyCompany_Catalog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>            
            <catalog>
                <class>MyCompany_Catalog_Block</class>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <catalog>
                <class>MyCompany_Catalog_Helper</class>
            </catalog>
        </helpers>
    </global>    
</config>`

Comment: I think the credit goes to clockworkgeek, but it seems the problem is your xml. I don't know about replacing whole modules but I mostly use rewrite as follows: `<global><blocks><catalog><rewrite><product_price>MyCompany_Catalog_Block_Product_Price</product_price></rewrite></catalog></blocks></global>`.

Comment: Thanks for replying but its not helping. In fact thats what I'm trying to do:
`<p class="old-price">
                <span class="price-label"><?php /*echo $this->__('Regular Price:'); */echo $this->newPriceText(); ?></span>                
            </p>`
and newPriceText(); function is in /local/MyCompany/Catalog/Block/Product/Price.php
I have changed the xml as you suggested but still the error.

Comment: And you did refresh the cache? Probably, but it's so often a forgotten thing..

Comment: I am still waiting for the answer. Please help... I have tried changing the xml as Lucasmus suggested but still the same error. Really need this working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trace says:

> Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price::**testPrice**(Array())

which is different from the method **`newPriceText()`** that you have defined in the block and are also calling in your template.

Scan your template for `testPrice()` or `$this->testPrice()` calls.

Maybe you originally had defined a method named `testPrice`, then deleted it, or changed its name to `newPriceText` afterwards, but forgot to remove/rename the method calls in your template accordingly.